How do I use Terraform kubectl provider from inside cluster?
I am trying to get the Terraform kubectl provider to work from inside an EKS cluster without success.
I can apply my manifest from outside the cluster but from inside a pod I get an error: "failed to create Kubernetes rest client for update of resource: unknown". I think this might be with the way I'm configuring the provider.
I have these env values:
KUBE_LOAD_CONFIG_FILE=false
KUBE_HOST=https://kubernetes.default.svc

I'm sure I must have to define how to authenticate to the cluster, but I don't know how to do that.
Is there an example of using this provider from inside EKS?

Would you mind explaining the need to use the provider from inside of the cluster?

Running Atlantis inside Kubernetes, where the project being built by Atlantis wants to define resources inside the cluster.

You need to assign a ServiceAccount to the deployment which has access to the required resources (via Role and RoleBinding).
Next you can use the mounted token and CA cert inside the container. Something like this should work
provider "kubectl" {
  host                   = "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
  cluster_ca_certificate = file("/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt")
  token                  = file("/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token")
  load_config_file       = false
}

Note that the token will expire after 60 min and be renewed by kubernetes. Not sure if the provider can refresh the token.
